# How can I make schematic of this board?

Tags: power-supply, schematic

I want to make a schematic of this board.

Can anyone tell me how?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a single layer PCB, should be relatively easy. Mark each metal trace with a different letter, write them down in a table. Then for each letter write down which component (and which pin of it) is connected to it. After you have done this, you will have kind of a "netlist". From there you can start drawing. Draw points, as many as you have the letters. Annotate each one with the letters as above, then draw the components between them. Once you have finished you have a schematic. An ugly and an unorganized one, but from there you can start redrawing it.

Comment: Also note connections that are thicker or have soldered regions.

Answer (score 11):

My personal favorite way is to take a photo of the board from directly overhead, flip the board over, and photo the bottom.  Keep the camera exactly the same distance away (a mount helps.) Then take these images, with software like PhotoShop or GIMP, and flip the bottom image horizontally, and stack these on top of each other as layers.  Then you can play with transparency to "see" both sides of the board at the same time.

Then you can see what pins of what components connect to what. I'd make another layer, and sketch the symbols of what the components actually are. Then add "wires" following the bottom traces to result in a "schematic."

Once that is done, hide the photos and look at just the schematic.  It will be valid, but drawn horribly. From there, I would enter this into a schematic capture program such as KiCAD.  Then rearrange things to make it understandable and to follow [schematic convention](https://sites.ntc.doe.gov/partners/tr/Training%20Textbooks/08-Engineering%20Symbology,%20Prints,%20and%20Drawings/4-Mod%204-Electronic%20Diagrams%20and%20Schematics.pdf) (from doe.gov).

Note that there is a lot more to schematic convention than this one linked document. It is also slightly wrong in my opinion, or at least old-hat, as I was taught that transistor arrows should always point downwards or right. Grounds should always point down. Inputs always on the left, outputs on right.

Edit: Once you have an image like @Mattman944 demonstrates, start sketching on a new layer like the following:

[image: Started schematic sketch]

Once done, redraw it to look possibly similar to this (courtesy Power Integrations):
[image: TOPswitch example]

Answer (score 4):

This is the first step, like *rdtsc* recommended. Since your images are skewed, I used the Photoshop *distort* transform to square and align the front and back. The transparency is set to 50%.

Next, draw a schematic ...

It would probably take me 5 hours or so to create a decent schematic. There are SMPS specialists here that could do it faster. Since you are a beginner, it might take you 20-50 hours.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a <s>two</s> one-sided pcb.

Make sure you discharge all the capacitors (short them one by one with care especially on the high side of the PCB).

use your multimeter on "short/beep" mode to see which component connects to what. You can trace the traces and see what/where to probe.

It does not have many traces, almost all of them are through hole so it should be easy.

Look at the IC's name, google it to see what IC is it exactly.

The only thing I am not sure of, is how you will figure out what is the inductance of the primary/secondary winding of the coil.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to disassemble the transformer too to see the number of turns if you plan on replicating the circuit. Completely relying on multimeter is not a good idea but you can use it to help you in the process. Using a CAD software with pre-installed libraries will be helpful in reducing the work done to find pinout of the components. Or you could hire someone to do the job and not learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't take so much time as Mattman944 said. Download [Fritzing](https://fritzing.org/) and assemble and connect the same electronic components from your PCB in 'breadboard view' (duplicate your PCB in Fritzing) and the schematics will automatically appear in Fritzing's 'schematic view'.