Finding it hard to track connections when they are under the protoboard/perfboard
What I really like about creating the connections underneath the protoboard/perfboard is that you can create really compact circuits. Also, since there's no insulation, it's easier to make multiple connections.
However, I find it hard to remember the connections. I have to constantly flip the circuit around to check, and sometimes I have to check more than once.
Did you also have this problem? Did it make you decide to make the connection above the board with jumper wires?

Also posted here.

At that point, a custom PCB is usually the next step. They're surprisingly cheap these days.

what do you mean by track connections ? ... what are you checking when you flip the board? ...  it is unclear what the problem actually is

@jsotola I'm checking whether I'm connecting the right leads or pins.

the picture shows pins labeled on the board ... why don't you label your pins? ... then you wouldn't have to remember ... at this point, your problem appears to be inadequate documentation

Do you follow a plan such as a schematic or work directly on the proto boars on an ad-hoc level? Guess which one requires less double/triple/quadruple/constant checking how something is/was connected? I mean, why do you even need to track or remember them?

I used to do a lot of hand wiring using thin enamelled wire and the soldering heat would burn off the insulation in order to make a connection. All I can say is practice - you end up mentally mapping your view without thinking. PLCC sockets were a challenge though.

Get out the multimeter and put it in continuity mode, if you need to probe the connector then use an alligator clip or 0.1" header

Take a digital photo of the top of the board, use a photo editor to mirror the photo, and then print it. That's your reference, it the same orientation as the bottom of the board.

Yes. And if you have some Photoshop skills, you can combine the top and bottom (set top layer to about 50%). https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/562349/how-can-i-make-schematic-of-this-board/562507#562507
